Eureka Spring application registration from KO to UP
I have a problem, in order to have the services registered correctly on Eureka Spring I have to restart the weblogic servers and deployments specifically and sequentially, otherwise Eureka does not register the applications correctly on both 'zones'.  My idea is to make a script that when only one application or all of them, including the weblogic servers, has to be restarted, it is registered on Eureka via a script without having to restart everything instead.
I have already tried giving this command to change the status of the application but without success:
curl -s -X "PUT" "http://localhost:porta/eureka/apps/application/instanceID/status?value=UP"

Thank you.
Best Regards,
